# If any Promise is rejected, how do you count the number of success in Promise.all?

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm currently trying to figure out if it is possible to do something like this:

```
async function(x) {
  ...
}

try {
  await Promise.all([function(1), function(2), function(3), ...]);
} catch (err) {
  // Count number of successful Promises resolved at the point when one is rejected
  return statistics(num_success);
}
```

Is this possible? The reason I am trying to do this in the catch block is so that I can terminate the function immediately if any errors.

If it is possible to do so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: see Promise.allSettled

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO but wouldn't Promise.allSettled mean that the program won't terminate immediately when any error occurs?

Comment: @zoobiedoobie but you *don't* want it to terminate immediately anyway, right? If you want to terminate on the first error, then what is the point of checking how many promises fulfilled successfully?

Comment: Furthermore there seems to be a misunderstanding about the "termination" of `Promise.all` once one of the promises failed: Just because `Promise.all` rejects on the first  rejected promise of it's parameters, that *doesn't mean that the pending promises stop executing*. Unless you explicitly kill the process the runtime will continue until there's nothing left on the eventqueue (ie all promises either resolved or rejected)

Answer (score 1):

as [Raphael PICCOLO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4181222/raphael-piccolo) commened, you can use `Promise.allSettled<T = any>(...promises: Promise<T>[])`. It returns a promise of array containing objects with `status` property, assigned with "fulfilled" or "rejected", according to each promise fulfillness or rejectness. A `value` property will be available if promise has fulfilled and, in case it rejects, a `reason` property will be available instead.

Example code:

```js
//...

const promises = []; //Array with promises.
let count = 0;

Promise.allSettled(promises)
    .then(settled => {
        settled.forEach(({ status, value, reason }) => {
            if (status === 'fulfilled')
                count++;
        })
    })
    .then(() => statistics(count));

//...
```

Comment: While you are in principle correct with `Promise.allSettled` your code doesn't make any sense, because `Promise.allSettled` resolves with an array, which you would have to iterate. Your first `then` expects only  a single object.

Comment: Oh my, that's true, @derpirscher, let me correct this one

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like all of your promises to run until they're settled (fulfilled or rejected), you can do so with [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) as in [Raphael PICCOLO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4181222/raphael-piccolo)'s comment and [SrHenry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68894041/1426891).

However, to preserve Promise.all's behavior of reacting to a rejection immediately, you'll need some additional custom behavior. This sounds like a good reason to wrap Promse.all.

```js
/**
 * Receives an array, like Promise.all, and runs until the first rejection.
 *
 * Unlike Promise.all, but like Promise.allSettled, this will always resolve
 * to an object; however, like Promise.all, this will resolve as soon as it
 * encounters the first rejection.
 *
 * Returns a promise that resolves to an object with these properties:
 *   success: boolean, whether Promise.all would have succeeded
 *   count: number, number of resolved Promises at the time of return
 *   results: Array, result array containing all resolved Promises/values
 *   error: any, the reject value that caused this to fail, or null
 */
function allWithProgress(arrayOfPromises) {
  const results = new Array(arrayOfPromises);
  let count = 0;
  
  /**
   * Given an input to Promise.resolve, increments results+count 
   * when complete.
   */
  function wrap(valueOrThenable, index) {
    return Promise.resolve(valueOrThenable).then(x => {
      results[index] = x;
      count++;
      return x;
    });
  }
  
  // slice(0) prevents the results array from being modified.
  // You could also add a condition check that prevents `wrap` from
  // modifying the results after it returns.
  return Promise
    .all(arrayOfPromises.map(wrap)) // or "(e, i) => wrap(e, i)"
    .then(x => ({success: true, count, results: results.slice(0), error: null}))
    .catch(e => ({success: false, count, results: results.slice(0), error: e}));
}

// Test harness below

function timeoutPromise(string, timeoutMs) {
  console.log("Promise created: " + string + " - " + timeoutMs + "ms");
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Promise resolved: " + string + " - " + timeoutMs + "ms");
      resolve(string);
    }, timeoutMs);
  });
}

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  // success
  return allWithProgress([
    timeoutPromise("s1", 1000),
    timeoutPromise("s2", 2000),
    timeoutPromise("s3", 3000),
    "not a promise"
  ]).then(console.log);
}).then(() => {
  // failure
  return allWithProgress([
    timeoutPromise("f1", 1000),
    timeoutPromise("f2", 2000)
      // rejects with a String for Stack Snippets; use an Error in real code 
      .then(() => Promise.reject("f2 failed")),
    timeoutPromise("f3", 3000),
    "not a promise"
  ]).then(console.log);
});
```

Note that ES6 Promises can't be canceled or rolled back in any standard way, so in the test case `f3` is not prevented from completing. If it is important to *stop* those promises in flight, you'll need to write that logic yourself.

Comment: While this code surely solves the original requirement of only counting the promises which already fulfilled when the first promise rejects, please be aware that this **won't** stop the runtime from executing the still pending promises until they are either rejected or resolved. This can also be seen in the output of the above snippet, ie it will still print `Promise resolved f3` eventhough it only resolves AFTER f2 already rejected (it won't be counted in the output though)!

Comment: If such a behaviour is intended, this can only be done by making all the promises aware of some shared state and each of them must reject, once at least one of them rejected.

Comment: Please note, that I have no intention of badmouthing this well formulated answer. I just wanted to point out the limitations of the technology (and a possible misunderstanding from the side of the OP)

Comment: @derpirscher That's a fair note to add; thank you. I'm well aware of that property, and wrote the test case deliberately to illustrate it, but you're right that I didn't call it out in my documentation. That said, the inability to meaningfully abort or rollback a Promise is an inherent property of ES6 Promises, and not one that the question-asker alluded to or challenged, so I'll leave it as a footnote unless the OP clarifies that they need that behavior.

Comment: I surely assumed that *you* are very well aware of these limitations, so my comments were directed towards OP ... Because the way the original question and the comments below are formulated, I have the impression, OP expects the remaining promises to stop executing immediately.

Comment: Fair. I read the goal as ending the program and printing progress statistics, disregarding cleanup for the Promises in flight since ideally the app will exit anyway. In that case the open question isn't really about canceling the promises in flight, unless the open promises keep Node from exiting properly.